# WSO2 identity server and ESB on same server

Tags: authentication, installation, authorization, single-sign-on, wso2-esb

We are installing a simple WSO2 identity server instance and a WSO2 EBS instance (for Authn and Authz).  Can I install both on the same windows server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install. But you need to set carbon offset parameter [1] to avoid port conflicts. You can change it in the carbon.xml of the server.

```
`<ports>
<Offset>1</Offset>
</ports>`
```

[1] http://srinathsview.blogspot.com/2011/08/offset-property-in-any-wso2-server.html